# How to connect backend with frontend while froking uniswap?

Tags: reactjs, interface, react-hooks, fork, solidity

I am trying to fork uniswap. I successfully deployed 'uniswap-core' and 'periphery' to the ganache. But I don't know how to connect the 'uniswap-interface' with the deployed contracts. Any help?